# How to add field belonging to a date?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want user to select month and year. On 1 column, there would be days[eg: 1-30] of month they selected. User then can add Habits on other columns. I want those user to be able to put 'X' in that row of the date[eg: 29, X, X,  , X], those columns being Date, Habit1, Habit2, Habit3, Habit4.

I am stuck on what to do ahead.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './HabitTable.css';

function HabitTable() {

  const today = new Date();
  const todayDate = today.getDate();
  const daysArray = [];

  const [month, setMonth] = useState('');
  const [year, setYear] = useState('');
  const [dateArray, setDateArray] = useState([]);
  const [dailyHabits, setDailyHabits] = useState([]); 

  const [addHabit, setAddHabit] = useState('');

  function addHabits() {
        if (addHabit.trim() !== '') {
      const updatedHabits = [...dailyHabits];
      updatedHabits.push(addHabit);
      setDailyHabits(updatedHabits);
      setAddHabit(''); 
   }
    
  }

  function getCorrectDates(month, year) {
    const numDays = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();

    for (let i = 0; i < numDays; i++) {
      daysArray[i] = i + 1;
    }

    return daysArray;
  }

  function handleDates() {
    setDateArray(getCorrectDates(month, year));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='select-dates'>
        <input placeholder='month' onChange={(e) => setMonth(e.target.value)} />
        <input placeholder='year' onChange={(e) => setYear(e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={handleDates}>Submit</button>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h1>Days</h1>
        <div>
          <input placeholder='add habit' value={addHabit} onChange={(e) => setAddHabit(e.target.value)} />
          <button onClick={addHabits}>Add</button>
        </div>
        <div className='days'>
          {dateArray.map((day) => (
            <div key={day}>
              <input disabled placeholder={day} />
            </div>
          ))}
          {Object.keys(dailyHabits).map((habitKey) => (
            
            <input key={todayDate} placeholder={dailyHabits[habitKey] + todayDate} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './HabitTable.css';

function HabitTable() {
  const [month, setMonth] = useState('');
  const [year, setYear] = useState('');
  const [dateArray, setDateArray] = useState([]);
  const [dailyHabits, setDailyHabits] = useState([]);
  const [addHabit, setAddHabit] = useState('');

  function addHabits() {
    if (addHabit.trim() !== '') {
      const updatedHabits = [...dailyHabits];
      updatedHabits.push(addHabit);
      setDailyHabits(updatedHabits);
      setAddHabit('');
    }
  }

  function getCorrectDates(month, year) {
    const numDays = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
    const daysArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < numDays; i++) {
      daysArray[i] = i + 1;
    }

    return daysArray;
  }

  function handleDates() {
    setDateArray(getCorrectDates(month, year));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='select-dates'>
        <input placeholder='month' onChange={(e) => setMonth(e.target.value)} />
        <input placeholder='year' onChange={(e) => setYear(e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={handleDates}>Submit</button>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h1>Days</h1>
        <div>
          <input
            placeholder='add habit'
            value={addHabit}
            onChange={(e) => setAddHabit(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button onClick={addHabits}>Add</button>
        </div>
        <div className='days'>
          {dateArray.map((day) => (
            <div key={day}>
              <input disabled placeholder={day} />
              {dailyHabits.map((habit, index) => (
                <input key={index} placeholder={habit} />
              ))}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HabitTable;
```